# Not redirecting after successful log in

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, touch

I am using this function to redirect my user if their password is validate:

```
if (ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket tkt;
            string cookiestr;
            HttpCookie ck;
            tkt = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtUsername.Text, DateTime.Now,
      DateTime.Now.AddHours(12), chkPersistCookie.Checked, "your custom data");
            cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tkt);
            ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
            if (chkPersistCookie.Checked)
                ck.Expires = tkt.Expiration;
            ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
            Response.Cookies.Add(ck);

            string strRedirect;
            strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
            if (strRedirect == null)
                strRedirect = "default.aspx";

            Response.Redirect(strRedirect, true);
        }
        else
            lblStatus.Text = "Incorrect Username or Password, please try again.";
```

It works fine on every browser on every platform I have tested it on, except on IE on my Surface tablet. Either through the Metro app or the desktop version. It just reloads back to the original blank log on screen. Has anyone had this issue?

Comment: Is it set to accept cookies?

Comment: Yes, I have added this as both a managed site and set the tablet to accept all cookies.